# Xamarin Forms : How to fix Activity Indicator in Centre of Screen in Scrollview

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uiscrollview

I have a `ScrollView` over `AbsoluteLayout`..
I need to Fix the postion of the ActivityIndicator in centre of screen.
I tried following code.

```
<ScrollView>
    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White"
                     Padding="50,20,50,20"
                     Spacing="5"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"> 
            // have set of elements..
        </StackLayout>
        <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                           IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                           Color="Black"
                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,0.1,0.1"
                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and I find the result as its in the centre of the `ScrollView`.

I tried by placing the `ActivityIndicator`out side the `ScrollView`it simply gives white screen as output.

How do I fix the position of the `ActivityIndicator` in centre of screen ?

Comment: can you share screen-shot of view.

Comment: If you want to put ActivityIndicator outside your ScrollView, you gotta put both ActivityIndicator and ScrollView inside an AbsoluteLayout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Vahid said, if you want the `ActivityIndicator` over the `ScrollView`, you need to put both inside an AbsoluteLayout, like this:

```
<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White"
                     Padding="50,20,50,20"
                     Spacing="5">
            // Your stuff goes here
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="#22000000"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,1,1"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}">
        <ActivityIndicator Color="Black"
                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,0.1,0.1"
                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                           IsVisible="True"
                           IsRunning="True"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Notice that I added an extra `AbsoluteLayout` that works like a 'wait overlay' over the `ScrollView` only - not the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

Create a grid page with one row and one column.
Define both your ActivityIndicatorLayout and ScrollLayout to be in row 0 and column 0.  I add the Content before the Activity Indicator.

Comment: It do works too, I've tested it. But I believe that AbsoluteLayout is a more efficient layout than Grid in respect to rendering performance.

Comment: That's right.. it works too.. since i saw some other solutions saying its only the way... i need more ways to discover.. and I feel AbsoluteLayout is more efficient solution.

Comment: Way back when this was the method recommended by Jason Smith, but I don't know if things have changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)

Design popup page with activity indicator and you can display it wherever you want.