# Why do controls become uncentered after adding activity indicator

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

I've been playing around with activity indicators, trying to get them added to my views, have it centered, have it overlay on top of other controls, etc.

The accepted answer in this other thread ([Xamarin Forms : How to fix Activity Indicator in Centre of Screen in Scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295792/xamarin-forms-how-to-fix-activity-indicator-in-centre-of-screen-in-scrollview)) actually shows me how to do all of that so I've added it to a test project to verify.

The problem I'm having is now after I add the controls to the XAML it now moves the controls to the top left of the screen and I'm wondering what I now need to change to get my controls centered again.

Here's my XAML in my test project:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="ActivityIndicator.MainPage">

<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <!-- Place new controls here -->
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <Button Text="Button1"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>

    <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="#22000000"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,1,1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                IsVisible="True">
        <ActivityIndicator Color="Black"
                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,0.1,0.1"
                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                       IsVisible="True"
                       IsRunning="True"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: You should have to position correctly Absolute LayoutBound.
[Absolute Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout) Have you tried this([Acr](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/)) it will be easy for you to work with it?
[How to Use](https://devlinduldulao.pro/how-to-use-acr-userdialogs/)

Comment: thanks Bharath. is there a way to bind this to an activity indicator with IsBusy? the example shows all the code tied directly to a button and then its displaying for a set time limit so im confused how i would convert that over to work with my app

Comment: i actually think i figured it out. ill give this a shot. thanks Bharath

Comment: @user1818298, Anything update, if my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you just want put ActivityIndicator in center of screen, I do one sample that you can take a look:

```
<RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Grid
            x:Name="SegmentGrid"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />


            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" />

            <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Button1" />
            <ActivityIndicator
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                IsRunning="True"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Color="Black" />
        </Grid>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it as follows. I created a method in my viewmodelbase that encapsulates the execution of an action.

```
`protected async Task ExecuteAndWait(Action action)
    {
        var popup = new PopupWaiting();
        IPopupNavigation ipn = PopupNavigation.Instance;
        await ipn.PushAsync(popup);
        action.Invoke();
        await ipn.RemovePageAsync(popup);
    }`
```

I'm using the Rg.Plugins.Popup.Contracts plugin to manage the loading layer.
The advantage of this model is that it does not have to change the xaml.