# How to use a ListView in Xamarin Forms and keep it from growing to big

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to display a list with about 30 to 40 items that the user has to choose from, and I don't wont to use a combobox, so a Listview seems the way to go.
However, once I put a listview on the page, the listview grows so much in height that it goes off the screen, how can I prevent that ?

I need something like this

```
<gttCompound:PageBase   xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                   xmlns:gttCompound="clr-namespace:gttCompound.Pages"
                   x:Class="gttCompound.Pages.PageDamageSelectFromList">

    <gttCompound:PageBase.ChildStackLayoutContent>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="5, 5">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="SELECT THE DAMAGE LOCATION" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeLabelSmall}" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" ></Label>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout x:Name="entirePage" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                    <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="Red">
                        <!-- ListView Stuff -->
                    </ListView>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <Button x:Name="ButtonDamageBack" WidthRequest="150" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextTransform="Uppercase" Text="{Binding Back}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ElementBackgroundColor}" TextColor="{StaticResource ElementTextColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeButtonLittle}" />
                <Button x:Name="ButtonDamageNext" WidthRequest="150" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextTransform="Uppercase" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Next}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ElementDisabledBackgroundColor}" TextColor="{StaticResource ElementTextColor}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeButtonLittle}" />
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
        
    </gttCompound:PageBase.ChildStackLayoutContent>
```

I gave some elements a noticable background color so I can see how much space they take
The listview takes way to much space.

Might it be because the page is an inherited page ?
The base page looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="gttCompound.Pages.PageBase"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:gttCompound.Pages.Helpers">
    <ContentPage.Resources>    
        <ResourceDictionary>    
            <helpers:StringNewLineConverter x:Key="StringNewLineConverter"/>    
            <helpers:StringToTitleCaseConverter x:Key="StringToTitleCaseConverter"/> 
            <helpers:StringSubstringConverter x:Key="StringSubstringConverter"/> 
        </ResourceDictionary>    
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    
    
    <!-- All the stuff about the AbsoluteLayout is to get a WaitCursor that can show in the center of the screen, see this url
         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295792/xamarin-forms-how-to-fix-activity-indicator-in-centre-of-screen-in-scrollview
    -->
    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ScrollView  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout>

                <StackLayout x:Name="TopStackLayout" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource HeaderColor}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Frame VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource HeaderColor}" BorderColor="Transparent" WidthRequest="40">
                        <Button x:Name="ButtonBack" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="" Image="Back.png" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource HeaderColor}" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" FontSize="8" HeightRequest="14" />
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource HeaderColor}" BorderColor="Transparent">
                        <Label Text="{Binding AppName}" HorizontalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeLabelBig}" Padding="0" x:Name="Page_Title" />
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout x:Name="ChildStackLayout" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,-6">
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout x:Name="BottomStackLayout" VerticalOptions="End" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource HeaderColor}">
                    <Label x:Name="LabelUser" Text="" TextColor="White" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeLabelTiny}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource HeaderColor}" Margin="0,0,0,-6" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" IsVisible= "True" />
                    <Label x:Name="LabelVersion" Text="" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  TextColor="White" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeLabelTiny}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource HeaderColor}" Margin="0,0,0,-6" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" IsVisible= "True" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding CopyRight}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource HeaderColor}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="White" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeLabelTiny}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="LayoutWaitCursor" BackgroundColor="#22000000" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" IsVisible="false">
            <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="true" IsRunning="True" Color="{StaticResource TextColor}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,0.1,0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is how the form looks like at runtime

[image]

And without the listview it looks like this
I changed just this

```
            <StackLayout x:Name="entirePage" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                    <!--
                    <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="Red">
                    </ListView>
                -->
            </StackLayout>
```

[image]

What I want is that the listview is visible and scrollable, but the 2 buttons should always stay visible. The listview must only occupy the space between the label on top of the page and the 2 buttons on the bottom of the page.
How can I do that ?

Comment: A ListView is inherently scrollable.  It doesn’t need to be inside a scrollView

Comment: @Jason That is just an attempt to restrict if from growing of my page, I can remove it but it makes no difference

Comment: Looking at it again, the real problem is the StackLayout.  A StackLayout will grow as needed to fit its contents.  You either need to put a HeightRequest on the ListView to constrain it, or use a different type of container

Comment: @Jason I cannot use a heightrequest I don't know on what device this will be running. What other container can I use then ?

Comment: @Jason And why does it grows so big for an empty listview ? I am new to xamarin forgive my ignorence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** REMOVE ScrollView.

**2)** `<StackLayout x:Name="ChildStackLayout" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ...`. Try different `VerticalOptions`. Try `Center`. Also try `CenterAndExpand`..

**3)** If still wrong, change the outer `StackLayout` to `Grid`, and use `RowDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto"`, with the 3 sections marked `Grid.Row="0"` / "1" / "2".
`ChildStackLayout` is "1" (numbered from `0`), so gets the `*` in RowDefinitions.

Comment: It took some fiddling but I got it working without the scrollview and switching to a grid, thank you